Content security policy Issue for ZAP scan with -unsafe-inline' option
In my application, I am configuring the Content Security Policy for script-src and style-src. When I include the 'unsafe-inline' option, it raises a vulnerability issue during the ZAP security scan. To address this, I removed all inline styles and scripts from the application. However, we are still encountering the same issue.
I created a sample Angular project, but I'm facing the same problem there as well. Can we set a Content Security Policy without using the 'unsafe-inline' option?
https://github.com/vinuvatassery/CSP-Implementation-main
Note: I have also tried using SHA and nonce, but those solutions are not working either.

If you're no longer using in-line scripts or styles then remove the directive from your policy.

I am not giving 'unsafe-inline' option and it is giving me CSP error like below
app.component.html:5  Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-XGYGoKIk88IyhvKNoTx7mpj0KKQwHNr9IRjk+Slrey4='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
